# Android video calling app with specific features

Tags: gratis, android, video-conferencing

Can anyone recommend an Android video calling app with the following features:

- Does not require a phone number
- Low latency
- Gratis for the app and for calls

It only needs to be able to connect to another person using the same app... it does not need to connect to other video calling clients, nor does it need to connect to a group of clients.

So far, I have tried the following, and they all required a telephone number:

- imo free video calls
- Google Duo
- Signal Private Messenger
- Viber Messenger
- WhatsApp Messenger
- JusTalk

Comment: Not using any app with the given specs, my usual comment: additional candidates can be found [in my corresponding app-listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_cheapcall#group_72) :)

Comment: Try [**Gruveo**](https://www.gruveo.com/)